Issues with RPC Requests in ThingsBoard: User Mismatch
I'm working with ThingsBoard and encountering an issue related to RPC requests. Currently, the system seems to only recognize one user per device. Specifically, when multiple users are connected to a device and one of them makes an RPC request, the output from the "Originator Fields node" always returns the username of user 'A', even if the request was initiated by user 'B'.
Is there a way to ensure that I receive the username of the user who actually made the RPC request, rather than the one currently associated with the device? Additionally, I’ve noticed that when updating attributes, the correct data comes through without issues.
Any insights or solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated!
I have followed the recommended approach by using the Change Originator and Originator Fields node.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
